# Using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() for setting path

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to store a database along with apk file but the application doesnt seem to find the database when i tried to hard code the path.

I was using this for hard coding the path but doesnt work.

```
private final String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.example.shopkart/databases/";  
        private final String Db_NAME = "dbshopkart.db";
```

How do i set the path for the above database using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

please help..

EDIT: my datamanager class

```
public class openingclass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public openingclass(Context c) {
        super(c, Db_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        createDataBase();
    }

    public void createDataBase() {

        boolean dbExist;
        try {
            dbExist = checkDataBase();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error("database dose not exist");

        }

        if (dbExist) {
            //do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + "/" + Db_NAME;

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            //database does't exist yet.
            throw new Error("database does't exist yet.");

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        //copyDataBase();
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = c1.getAssets().open(Db_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + "/" + Db_NAME;
        File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH);
        // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
        if (!databaseFile.exists()) {
            databaseFile.mkdir();
        }

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
05-03 11:26:21.713: E/Database(4612): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.example.shopkart/databases/dbshopkart.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
05-03 11:26:21.713: W/dalvikvm(4612): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612): java.lang.Error: database does't exist yet.
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at com.example.shopkart.datamanager$openingclass.checkDataBase(datamanager.java:114)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at com.example.shopkart.datamanager$openingclass.createDataBase(datamanager.java:65)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at com.example.shopkart.datamanager$openingclass.<init>(datamanager.java:57)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at com.example.shopkart.datamanager.<init>(datamanager.java:48)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at com.example.shopkart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-03 11:26:21.721: E/AndroidRuntime(4612):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Since your database is on the internal storage, the external storage discovery methods are not applicable.  The internal storage discovery method given in scottt's answer will work, but you must use it with a valid Context.  If you are using this in a class that does not extend Context, you may have to pass in the context of your Application or of an Activity class that does, or simply obtain the path there and pass it in.

Comment: It's really your method to copy the database from assets to a file that needs to discovery the proper database path for the android installation on the device, so it's probably that which you will need to pass a valid context to.  And your crash seems to be because you try to check the database before you've created it by copying it out of assets (or else you copied it to the wrong place, so it's still missing from the right one)

Comment: can u suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Now I see the real problem - when you do `throw new Error("database does't exist yet.");` you prevent ever reaching the code that would do the copy.  You shouldn't throw that error, as you are going to handle the situation yourself.

Comment: thanks chris, the app loads now..:)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method `getDatabasePath()`.

Since you're sending in a context as the parameter `c` in your constructor, then you can get the path there using c.getDatabasePath()`. Just save it as a class member if you need it in other places. Alternatively, you can save your context as a member and use that member in the call later.

Comment: Yes, but this can only be used in a class which inherits from Context, and perhaps only once it is fully started.

Comment: Now that you've added the code for your class, I've altered my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

All apps (root or not) have a default data directory, which is `/data/data/<package_name>`. By default, the apps databases, settings, and all other data go here.

By default your database will be stored in your `data/data/com.example.shopkart/databases/` directory only. You can view it using the `FileExplorer`. There is no need to specify explicit path.

So you don't need to specify path `"/data/data/com.example.shopkart/databases/";`. And the question about `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` so its used to specify the external storage path.

If you wish to store your database in sdcard then only you can go for `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` otherwise your database will be stored in `/data/data/com.example.shopkart/databases/"` by default though you don't specify.

Check out the [Directory structure](http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2014/01/android-storage-system-to-access-path.html) you will get idea about it.

**EDITED:**

Try out the below code for your database helper class.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private Context mycontext;


private static String DB_NAME ="dbshopkart.db"; //the extension may be .sqlite or .db
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException  {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.mycontext=context;
     ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
   private static String  DB_PATH =cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/Database/";
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if(dbexist)
    {
        //System.out.println("Database exists");
        opendatabase(); 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    createdatabase();
    }

}

public void createdatabase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if(dbexist)
    {
        //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
    }
    else{
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
            copydatabase();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkdatabase() {
    //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try{
        String myPath =DB_PATH +DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

    return checkdb;
}
private void copydatabase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename =DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();

}

public void opendatabase() throws SQLException
{
    //Open the database
    String mypath =DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}



public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDataBase != null){
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

Comment: THe method getDatabasePath is undefined for my class error!!

Comment: downvoter whats the problem ? Care to mention atleast.

Comment: THe datamanager class that i use for all database operations in my application is a plain java class , it doesnt extend activity.So how do i use a valid context there?

Comment: You should not assume the database path as that is implementation defined, and you cannot view it with a File Explorer unless you have one that depends on a root hack, or are viewing the database path of the Filer Explorer app rather than of your app.

Comment: i have added the datamanager class.When i debug the application on my phone it force closes.Can anyone post a specific solution for my application rather than telling what not to do.

Comment: @AchuthanM If it crash then post your logcat error.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ? Are you trying to copy your database from your assets ? @AchuthanM

Comment: yes, i have placed the database file in the assets folder.To be honest i just followed a tutorial on the net.But there is a line in the code which attempts to retrieve the database fromm the assets?.I have tried to run the code on the phone whose logcat i have placed here.

Comment: Do you have database in your assets folder ? Which tutorial you have followed ?

Comment: @AchuthanM Try out the database helper code which i have provided in my answer. And let me know still any issue.

Comment: -1 for hardcoding the database path again.  Don't do that, it's not portable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Updated answer. Now fine ?

Comment: Probably not.  The whole point of the question is that you do need to know the path, and to be safe you need to discover it at runtime, by passing in a valid context and calling the getDatabasePath() method - what the OPs code is attempting, and just short of succeeding at doing. So to my way of thinking, your solution is a step backwards.  Can you can demonstrate that the file can be written in the needed place without discovering the path?